# What does "for" in "defimpl" in Elixir actually checks for?

Tags: protocols, elixir

Does "for" always checks the type of first argument in each function defined in a protocol?

EDIT (rephrasing):
When protocol method has only one argument, implementation is found based on the type of this single argument (either direct or as Any). When protocol method has multiple arguments, which one is used to find the corresponding implementation? Is it always the first one? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation is always determined based on the first argument.

When you define a protocol, a generic protocol module will be generated. All `def` clauses in that module will perform delegations to concrete functions, determining which function to call based on the type of the first argument.

The place in Elixir source where this happens is [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.0.2/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L27) (where first argument is explicitly referred to as `t`), and [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/150a8a1dcd3610d5ff875e00a1c8779894456ca6/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L42) (where `t` is passed to `impl_for!` to obtain the module where the function call is forwarded).

A `defimpl` will generate concrete modules whose names adhere to the internal conventions used by `defprotocol`. Thus it is ensured that function call will be delegated to the proper concrete module.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that `for` defines what type the protocol implementation is for. When a function specified in a protocol is invoked on a value, Elixir checks to see if there is an implementation of that function for that type. Of course there are some special cases like fallback to `Any` and built in protocols. But to answer your question, yes, as far as I know, the type is always checked.

More can be learned by inspect the source code:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/150a8a1dcd3610d5ff875e00a1c8779894456ca6/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L522
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/150a8a1dcd3610d5ff875e00a1c8779894456ca6/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L456

**EDIT**

It appears that the type of the first argument is the only thing that matters.

Starting on line 28 in protocol.ex, it seems that the first argument is the only one that is taken into account: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/150a8a1dcd3610d5ff875e00a1c8779894456ca6/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L28

From what I understand **only the type of first argument is taken into account. The types of all the other values are ignored.**

Comment: I rephrased the question a little, hope it is now more clear. I understand that type is somehow checked, but I am not sure what exactly is being checked.

Comment: Thank you! I have a better understanding now.